# Using RVM gemsets inside of Vim

Tags: macos, vim, osx-lion, macvim

I have set up a `.rvmrc` file for my project, which simply looks like this

```
rvm use 1.9.3@myproj
```

My Vim workflow is to `:cd` into the project's directory and then use CommandT to navigate between files and execute specs via `:!bundle exec rspec %`.

The problem is, that when I add something to my Gemfile and run `bundle install` from terminal and then go back to MacVim, it tells me to run `bundle install` again.

When I do `:!rvm gemset gemdir`, it shows me that it's not using the desired gemset, meaning it returns only

```
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
```

instead of

```
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@myproj
```

I tried doing `:!rvm gemset use myproj` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
:!rvm gemset use myproj
/Users/darth/.rvm/bin/rvm: line 44: typeset: -g: invalid option
typeset: usage: typeset [-afFirtx] [-p] name[=value] ...

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

Using /Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0 with gemset myproj
```

because if I do `:!rvm gemset gemdir` right after that, it still returns the default path, not the `@myproj` gemset.

I'm using MacVim on OS X Lion, but I'm having the same problem in terminal Vim too.

Comment: anyone knows **why** this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [vim-rvm](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rvm). I didn't tried it yet but tpope wrote it. So, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, but unfortunately it looks like vim-rvm isn't working with the latest version of rvm. See this issue https://github.com/tpope/vim-rvm/issues/2

Comment: I see. We'll wait for a reply from tpope. He is always very clear about issues. I think he could fix it.